# Docker : how to have container visible on host only

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

I have containers that I want visible only for the host on a virtual network.
It's for a Windows Server 2016.

Example:

- I have a Mongo container with exposed port 27017
- The container address is 192.168.0.1
- Host address is X.Y.Z.A

=> I want to have Mongo reachable only on 192.168.0.1:27017.

If I use a docker NAT network for my container, Mongo is reachable on all interfaces (i.e. X.Y.Z.A:27017 is visible).

By the way, this command does not work on windows:

```
docker run 127.0.0.1:27017:27017 ...
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: do you use a configuration file or docker cli to run the container? what are the commands you use?

Comment: Don't map the port via `docker run` then mongo will only listen on the container address

Comment: I use cli to run the container : 
`docker run -p 27017:27017 -p 5000:5000 --detach --restart always -v xvolume:x: -v mongodb:C:\data\db --name rest rest:latest`

As you can see, I also need port 5000 reachable outside the container and I also need to have Mongo port reachable.